# When exactly do we use WCF transactions?

Tags: wcf, transactions

I was trying to get some info on WCF transactions, and I did manage to get info on how to use them. What I didn't get much info on is Why/When to use them.
What is the difference between database transactions and WCF transactions? Is there any specific case when either of these approach is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *WCF transactions* what you are really asking about is Microsoft's implementation of the [WS-AtomicTransaction](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.1-spec-os/wstx-wsat-1.1-spec-os.html) web service extension standard.

> Why/When to use them

Similar to using a database transaction to guarantee consistency within the database, WS-AtomicTransaction is used to guarantee consistency within a larger, distributed system, based on communication over SOAP 1.2 services. This distributed system may or may not include database writes, but more often than not it will do.

Transactions propagated to the service from clients will cause the internal code of the service to execute within the context of the clients transaction.

So, in that same way a database transaction can wrap multiple database writes into a single unit of work, a WCF transaction can wrap multiple service calls into a single unit of work, so that a failure in one will roll back the others.

This, as you can imagine, is hugely costly from a resource perspective, so these kinds of cross-network transactions should be rarely (if ever) used unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: So not too much of practical use for that.

Comment: @Kodathon - agreed. I have not seen distributed transactions of this type before. I think they are unpopular.